# DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: no name in Entity

Tags: php, warnings

I use this code to read html-files:

```
$doc = new DomDocument();
$filecontent = file_get_contents($path);
$doc->loadHTML($filecontent);
```

In the html-files there are &-characters in the text, which I can't remove. As a result, I get this warning:

```
DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: no name in Entity
```

I found two similar questions here on Stackoverflow. Nevertheless, I was not able to solve the problem, because I don't want to just supress the warnings.

Is there any smart way to get rid of the warning by using a function for converting the &?

Comment: Use `htmlentities` function for HTML text to convert & symbols

Comment: Looks like your source is not valid XML. Is that file HTML5 ?

Comment: Yes, HTML5. I removed the '&' to test it - that solved the problem. But unfortunately this is not possible for any file.